# How to understand E. G. White's (SDA) comment on the fourth commandment in Exodus 20:8?

Tags: exodus, kjv, sabbath, seventh-day-adventists, ellen-g-white

> Remember the sabbath day, to keep it holy. (Exodus 20:8 KJV)

> ... the Son of man is Lord also of the sabbath. (Luke 6:5 KJV)

In her commentary of the above text E. G. White says that the fourth commandment is the ***only one*** out of the ten which are found both the name and the title of the lawgiver, as well as the only one which shows by whose authority the law was given (PP307).

How to understand this interpretation?

Comment: The referenced quotation, Ex 20:8 KJV, says no more than the commandment itself. Where is the mention of 'the name and the title of the lawgiver' and 'authority'  ? Is E G White referring to other passages as well ?

Comment: @NigelJThat is exactly what 1 was questioning as well because i didn't see any reference to the name and the title of the lawgiver,maybe she is referring to other passages

Comment: I understand. Close-vote rescinded and question up-voted.

Comment: I am assuming this commentary applies to the whole Exodus 20:8-11, which multiple times mentions "the LORD thy God", but it still makes little sense as other commandments have the same expression.

Answer (score 1):

This interpretation comes from the complete commandment, not just the first verse.

What is interesting about the fourth commandment is that there is a description that follows it.  This detail is what adds to the interpretation.

> 8 “Remember the Sabbath day by keeping it holy. 9 Six days you shall
> labor and do all your work, 10 but the seventh day is a sabbath to the
> Lord your God. On it you shall not do any work, neither you, nor your
> son or daughter, nor your male or female servant, nor your animals,
> nor any foreigner residing in your towns.

It is verse 11 that describes the authority by linking to the creator.

> 11 For in six days the Lord made the heavens and the earth, the sea, and all that is in them, but
> he rested on the seventh day. Therefore the Lord blessed the Sabbath
> day and made it holy.

- NAME = The LORD (YHWH)
- TITLE = your God (v10)
- AUTHORITY = Creator -> Made heaven and earth...

The idea is that if you removed this commandment and its link to creation the uniqueness of the 10 commandments disappear and could be assigned to any god. Which as the story of the golden calf reveals, was a real risk.

This is an important link to the sabbath theme that runs through the bible. From Creation, to the Exodus, To the Gospel, to the second coming the Sabbath is visible through all of those.

Comment: Some interesting points. Up-voted +1. But I don't see them as conclusive, given the circumstances under which the commandments were delivered and the very substance upon which they were delivered and the person to whom they were delivered. The ten sayings are not in a vacuum. They were uttered in context.

Comment: That context never announces who God is, until the 4th.  It would be assumed by that point.  Kind of like the queen entering a room, but then an announcer declaring who she is.  

God describes himself as a creator again in Revelation 14:7 This is the link that adventist find important.  Gen 1 -> Ex 20 -> Rev 14